# How are Huge files stored in a database?

Tags: database, blob

I was just wondering how exactly huge files are stored in databases. Most BLOBs are limeted to  1GB as far as I know but if you take youtube for example, they have multiple full-HD videos with over an hour of running time (I think that's a bit larger than 1GB).

Are they using some kind of special database, is there another datatype I've never heard of or are they just using a simple method like splitting the files?

If they use let's say a method where they split and rearrange the bits and bytes, how can the end user look a video without noticing.

It's just a question out of pure curiosity but I would be happy if you could answer it.

Comment: Which database? MySQL?

Comment: With really big files i tend to store the file on the server and then just link them to it.   It really depends on the database you are running how well it would handle large files being stored in it.

Comment: This question is *completely* DBMS dependent. So you need to tell us which DBMS you are using. Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really the best idea to store files into a database. Youtube and other websites are web applications that store files in files systems. Databases are then only necessary to store information allowing to retrieve the required files on the file system before providing them to users.

Comment: Imagine billions accesses to a huge video! Database will be "stressed-out" by returning big BLOBs, CLOBs or whatever. An application server does the job very well and then the database will only have to return a path or similar simple data about the file.

Answer (score 0):

They could be stored on disk and use a DB to hold only the paths. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to store it as BLOB? you can just store it as a file ( FLV or whatever ) and just stream it from there.